# Plot ellipse on top of image array

Tags: python, matplotlib

What I have:

[image]

The bit of code that produces this:

```
implot = plt.imshow(array, cmap='gist_heat',interpolation="none")
plt.colorbar(implot, orientation='vertical')
plt.xlim(-PixVal,PixVal)
plt.ylim(-PixVal,PixVal)
```

Now, using the Ellipse from Patches in Matplotlib, I want to plot an ellipse on top of the array in the same plot above. How do I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Just using `ax.add_patch(Ellipse(...))` should do the trick. For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse

# create some data
x = np.arange(-8., 8.)
array = np.exp(-(x ** 2 + x[:, None] ** 2) / 30)
array += 0.5 * np.random.random(array.shape)

# draw the image
implot = plt.imshow(array, cmap='gist_heat',interpolation="none")
plt.colorbar(implot, orientation='vertical')

# draw the ellipse
ax = plt.gca()
ax.add_patch(Ellipse((8, 8), width=8, height=6,
                     edgecolor='white',
                     facecolor='none',
                     linewidth=5))
```

[image]